# How code python by CVS in eclipse different at locat and server?

Tags: python, eclipse, cvs

i use CVS to code on server by eclipse local ( eclipse on win 8)
when i create a file is test.py in project CVS 
but i see it is test.py,v on sever and
on local:

```
print 11111
```

on server:

```
head    1.1;
access;
symbols;
locks; strict;
comment @# @;


1.1
date    2013.12.07.03.35.50;    author username;    state Exp;
branches;
next    ;


desc
@@


1.1
log
@test
@
text
@print 11111@
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing isn't a problem.  The `test.py,v` file stores the complete revision history of `test.py`:  the current version and all past versions, including information about when each version was checked in and the comment that you wrote for each commit.  That's how CVS works.

CVS is old and has some major shortcomings, by the way.  You should strongly consider switching to something more modern, such as [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Subversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion).